# displaying wordpress pages not showing the correct format

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this PHP Code on my website to get wordpress page content from the database:

```
$page = get_page_by_id($records["value"], OBJECT, 'page');
    query_posts('p='.$page->ID.'');
    echo '<div id="page-title">'.$page->post_title.'</div>';
    echo nl2br($page->post_content);
    echo '<p>&nbsp;</p><hr /><p>&nbsp;</p>';
```

in wordpress, i have put the page with HTML and aligned images etc but when it displays on my website it just shows the images and text all under each other with the incorrect format (not as i put it in the text editor)

what have i done wrong here?

Comment: Why are you doing it like this? Are you familiar with how templates are supposed to work? I'd suggest looking at page.php inside one of the default themes such as TwentyThirteen / TwentyFourteen.

Comment: TwentyFourteen does not have page.php

Comment: As another user pointed out this theme does have a page.php it's just organised differently to previous default themes.

Answer (score 0):

Im also wondering why you are doing like this? there is no need to call post title and content that way. simply make a page.php. The TwentyFourteen does have page template but in a folder named "page-templates". You can simply make a page.php by sample code below.

```
<?php get_header(); ?> //the header template

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> //start the loop

<?php the_title(); ?> //Page Title

<?php the_content(); ?> //The content

<?php endwhile; ?> //end loop

<?php get_sidebar(); ?> //sidebar template

<?php get_footer(); ?> // footer template
```

you can add div / span wherever you want.